# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in domian.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

This is not a duplicate question as i aldredy found the same but this is a different one, i am getting this error i made corrections in nginx.conf and run the the test  sudo nginx -t , got test completed message. when adding the domain configuration for the same, i am getting this error, in domain if i place the server in http block the here test is successful and getting error in nginx.conf. The error is shifting vice versa.
nginx version installed is 1.14.1, OS Redhat enterprise linux 8.6.

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. It should become obvious why your `server` block is not nested within the `http` block.

Comment: [root@IRRIGATION_IDRB_APP1 sites-enabled]# sudo nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user  nginx;
events {   
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.idrbtest.com.conf:
server {
}
Like wise present

Comment: Use the Edit button to add additional information to your question.

Comment: resolved it beacuse at first nginx.conf and domaniname.conf are used, then i changed it to nginx.conf and used server inside the http the issue is resolved finally, thank you for your response with ngin -T, to look specifically into the issue. Here i am getting formatting issues while submitting large code so i am unable to submit the code here